# Linq to Entities OrderBy evaluates query earlier when keySelector is passed

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I'm implementing server-side paging using Entity Framework and have following code

```cs
 DbQuery<T> query = Context.Set<T>();

 query = IncludeNavigationProperties(query, includedProperties);

 var result =  query.OrderBy(arg => arg.DatabaseId)
                    .Skip((pageNumber - 1)*pageSize)
                    .Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

which generates me a SQL that queries only necessary data (checked with SQL Server Profiler)

```sql
SELECT TOP (21) 
[Extent1].[DatabaseId] AS [DatabaseId], 
...[other props here]...
FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[DatabaseId] AS [DatabaseId], ...[other props here]..., row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[DatabaseId] ASC) AS [row_number]
    FROM [dbo].[Table] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 84
ORDER BY [Extent1].[DatabaseId] ASC
```

Then I've decided to reuse this method in more scenarios and pass `keySelector` as a extern variable:

```cs
 DbQuery<T> query = Context.Set<T>();

 query = IncludeNavigationProperties(query, includedProperties);

 var result =  query.OrderBy(keySelector)
                    .Skip((pageNumber - 1)*pageSize)
                    .Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

where

```cs
Func<T, int> keySelector = arg => arg.DatabaseId;
```

But it suddenly generates following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT 
[Extent1].[DatabaseId] AS [DatabaseId], 
...[other props here]...
FROM [dbo].[Table] AS [Extent1]
```

which, as I understand, queries **all** data from Table and then processes it on server.

So, I have 2 questions:

1. Why does the query change?
2. How can I fix it (being able to vary `keySelector` and query only necessary data)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DbQuery<T>` derives from both `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` classes. Both of these classes provide `OrderBy` method with one difference: `OrderBy` on `IEnumerable` gets a `Func<T1,T2>` and `OrderBy` on `IQueriable` gets an `Expression<Func<T1,T2>>` parameter. When you pass `keyselector` as a `Func<T1,T2>` object to the `OrderBy` method, you tell the compiler: **Hey! Please use the `OrderBy` method which is defined on `IEnumerable`.** In other words your `DbQuery<T>` object gets casted to `IEnumerable<T>` not `IQueriable<T>.` This is why all the data are fetched to the client and furthur operations are done in-memory.

To fix this, change the type of `keyselector` from `Func<T1,TKey>` to `Expression <Func<T1,TKey>>` as:

```
public IQueriable<T> YourMethodName<T, TKey>(Expression<Func<T,TKey>> keyselector)
{
    DbQuery<T> query = Context.Set<T>();

     query = IncludeNavigationProperties(query, includedProperties);

     var result =  query.OrderBy(keySelector)
                        .Skip((pageNumber - 1)*pageSize)
                        .Take(pageSize).ToList();
     return result;
}
```